# Is it possible to return a application/json from a Spring Integration http inbound-channel-adapter?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have an inbound-channel-adapter that forwards message to router and router has one mapping property which calls service activator where I am trying to trigger one REST POST service which accepts input JSON and produce output JSON.

In this case, service activator reutrns null but since http has to return a response.(In inbound-channel-adapter, I am using status-code-expression="T(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus).NO_CONTENT"

I'm using spring-integration v4.3.6

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s possible. Since this component is one-way, there is nothing to return - just only status code header. By default it is 200 OK.

If you would like to return something, you should consider to use HTTP Inbound Gateway instead.

Otherwise your question isn’t clear